# CSS Flexbox: how to change the width of the element

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm using Flexbox in CSS. In the next link, you can see three squares lying one above the other: http://codepen.io/CrazySynthax/pen/PbLjMO
The first square is the smallest and the last square is the biggest. My question is how to draw these squares that their height will be identical, but their width will differ, so they will look like this:

> ```
> ---
> ------
> ---------
> ```

This is the code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="square"> </div>
  <div class="square"> </div>
  <div class="square"> </div>
</div>


html, body { 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  displax: flex;
}
.container{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow:column wrap;
  justify-content:space-around;

}
.square {
  flex:1 1 auto;
  background-color:gray;
  border:solid;
  margin: 1em;
}

.square:nth-child(1) { 
  flex-grow: 1
}

.square:nth-child(2) { 
  flex-grow: 2
}

.square:nth-child(3) { 
  flex-grow: 5
}
```

Comment: Why not pixels?

Comment: Rectangles, not squares

Comment: `flex-grow` works along the main-axis (the direction of the flex), so the width is affected by `flex-direction: row` and the height is affected by `flex-direction: column`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a class to each `div` with desired `width` & leave `flex-grow`s in `1` to maintain same `height`:

```css
html, body { 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  displax: flex;
}
.container{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow:column wrap;
  justify-content:space-around;
  
}
.square {
  flex:1 1 auto;
  background-color:gray;
  border:solid;
  margin: 1em;
  width: 200px
}
.square:nth-child(1) { 
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.square:nth-child(2) { 
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.square:nth-child(3) { 
  flex-grow: 1;
}
/*added classes*/
.one {
  width: 150px;
}
.two {
  width: 250px;
}
.three {
  width: 350px;
}

@media (max-width: 350px) {
   .one {
      width: auto;
   }
   .two {
      width: auto;
   }
   .three {
      width: auto;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="square one"></div>
  <div class="square two"></div>
  <div class="square three"></div>
</div>
```

EDIT: For responsive beyond 350px or whatever add a `@media` query (make sure it's set at the end of the CSS sheet or later than the custom `width` `.one` `.two` & `.three`):

Test resizing window on [external JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5a4yern1/)

```
@media (max-width: 350px) {
   .one {
      width: auto;
   }
   .two {
      width: auto;
   }
   .three {
      width: auto;
   }
}
```

Comment: My problem with this solution is that it's not responsive. You can't minimize the screen for less than 350px wide.